# Use parameter as a generic type, and also give it a default assignment

Tags: typescript

I have a simple class `Board` with parameters `width`, `height`, and `types` in the constructor. Height and width will always have the type `number`, but `types` is an array of any type.

What I would like to do is to capture the type of the `types` parameter using a generic type `<T>`. Then `T` can be used for the return of another function that uses `this.types`. The problem is that I also would like to set the default types to an array of numbers.

This is what I thought might work, but I currently get the error `Type 'number[]' is not assignable to Type 'T[]' Type 'number' is not assignable to Type 'T'`.

```
export class Board<T> {
    constructor(width: number = 8, height: number = 8, types: T[] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.types = types;
    }
    getTypes(): T[] {
        return this.types;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this setup even possible?

What I ultimately want is for the `T` to be assigned to whatever type that `this.types` ends up being after the class is instantiated. If I call `new Board(8, 8, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);`, I'd like it to know that `T` should be `string`. AND if I just call `new Board()` it will know that `T` should be `number`.

Comment: You can't use an array of numbers as default value for an array of `T`s, since you don't know whether `T` will be `number`. What would happen if you call `new Board<string>(8, 8)`?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but how can I set `T` to be dependent on whatever `this.types` is assigned to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Better approach** using [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
class Board<T> {
    private width:number;
    private height:number;
    private types:T[]|number[];

    constructor(width:number = 8, height:number = 8, types:T[]|number[] = [1, 2]) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.types = types;
    }

    getTypes():T[]|number[] {
        return this.types;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r8uqn760/2/

**Old answer** using [type alias](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#310-type-aliases):

This approach will always allow numbers in the **this.types** array.

For example `new Board(0, 0, [0, "foo"])` will pass at compilation, and I think it's not what you want to happen.

```
type X<Y> = number | Y;

class Board<T> {
    private width:number;
    private height:number;
    private types:X<T>[];

    constructor(width:number = 8, height:number = 8, types = [1,2] as X<T>[]) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.types = types;
    }

    getTypes():X<T>[] {
        return this.types;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8uqn760/)

Comment: I like this very much, and it can work for what I'm trying to do. I am curious however if there is a way to set an alias to be used within the class that references `this.types`. Something perhaps like `type Z = typeof this.orbs` and `getTypes(): Z[] { return this.types }`. I'm not seeing how to make that idea work though.

Comment: It's not possible to create type alias inside class. Please see updated answer as the old one had loophole.

Comment: Okay. This answer definitely gave me the information I needed. Really what I am looking for is a way to use a type alias inside the class, but alas, it cannot be done. In this case, it was best to just use `types: any[]`. It is less specific, but that is alright.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I find the original question and code too complicated. Here is an alternative (essentially telling the same):

**Question:** How can I have a default parameter in a constructor of a generics class? The following does not compile.

```
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(x: T = 42) {}
}
```

**Answer:** You can use [advanced types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) as a workaround:

```
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(x: T | number = 42) {}
}
```