# default parameter in constructor of generics class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

---

### This is a duplicate. But I find the original code/question too complicated.

In TypeScript I can have a generics class with a constructor like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(x: T) {}
}
```

And I can have default parameters like this:

```
function Bar(x: string = 'baz'): void {}
```

But how can I have a default parameter in the constructor? This does not compile:

```
class Foo2<T> {
    constructor(x: T = 'baz') {}
}
```

OK, applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38233862/1948252) the **solution** looks like this:

```
class Foo3<T> {
    constructor(x: T | string = 'baz') {}
}
```

Thanks to [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) for showing me in his comment (below).

Comment: I guess you mean class names. `constructor` is a keyword and has no name.

Comment: I mean constructor functions, which is what `class` syntax creates (but which can also be created via `function`, though without some features).

Comment: Why not? It shows doing what you're asking about: providing a default value for a parameter using (and determining) the generic type parameter for the class: [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6w8AdhAC4BOArsKfOQBQAeAXNCtAD7RnkCWRAc2gBeaACIARmABeYgJRYAvtmVA). It's imperfect, but sadly that's because TypeScript basically doesn't let you do it in a better way. Either way, the questions are asking fundamentally the same things.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think now I understand what I did wrong.

Comment: You're assigning a string to a generic type, which can but doesn't need to be a string. That's why you're getting an error.

Comment: @MikeS. My point is: The compiler **could** infer the type statically. If I call `new Foo2()` then `T` must be `string`. That's obvious to me.